# Created pointer but how to write in class?

Tags: visual-c++

I have initialized Queue *q1, *q2; but it could not create the Queue in my Queue class

Main

```
Queue *q1, *q2; // Global variable
```

Queue class

```
// codes......

Queue::Queue() { // default constructor
    size = 0;
    front = 0;
    rear = Q_MAX_SIZE -1;
}

Queue::~Queue() { 
    while(!isEmpty()) {
        dequeue();
    }
}

void Queue::enqueue(Car c) {
    if (!isFull()) {
        rear = (rear + 1) % Q_MAX_SIZE; // circular array
        carQueue[rear] = c;
        size++;
    } else {
        cout << "Queue is currently full.\n";
    }
}

// codes.....
```

I cannot seem to initialize the Queue with the default constructor cause in debugging mode, it cannot read any size, front and rear.

Answer (score 0):

The statement:
`Queue *q1, q2;`

Create one pointer variable (`Queue*`), and a normal variable of type `Queue`. Only for `q2`, which is of normal type `Queue`, the constructor will be called. You don't see constructor being called (in debugging mode), only because it is called BEFORE `main`, (or `WinMain`) - since it is global variable. Global variables are initialized before `main` routine.

You need to put a breakpoint with the constructor itself - `Queue::Queue()`.

Hope this helps.

Comment: you mean Queue::Queue(Queue* q) {
 size = 0;
 front = 0;
 rear = Q_MAX_SIZE -1;
}

Comment: I got another error instead. bool Queue::isFull() {
 if (size == Q_MAX_SIZE) {
  return true;
 }
 return false;
}
 Unhandled exception at 0x010d2ef6 in DSA_Assignment.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000000.

Comment: my global variable const int Q_MAX_SIZE 20; and local variable size is int size;

Comment: Please improve your accept-rate on StackOverflow. And please try to resolve the issue before just dumping the code/problem here!

Comment: you mean click onto the tick for my questions? ok.

Comment: I just want to find out how come it could not read my size. And Queue::isFull() is one of the affected ones..